# How can I simulate two endpoints that can both send and receive messages using RobotFramework?

Tags: robotframework

I have a use case where the System Under Test (SUT) communicates with two endpoints A and B.   The flow is basically:

1. A sends msg to SUT
2. SUT sends msg to B
3. B validates msg from SUT and sends response.

I have used the requests library to Send HTTP requests and check responses, but how can I "listen" on a Port and then respond accordingly?

I am thinking of writing my own library in Python to act as the listener, but wanted to know if someone else has solved this already

Comment: Do you have the ability to tell "B" where to send the response? How does it know to send the response to the test rather than to whatever it normally sends it to?

Comment: We can setup the SUT to send to any IP/Port we want.   "B" which is the RobotFramework program has in it specified the IP/Port of the SUT

Comment: None of the present libraries have a port listening functionality. So, from that perspective you are indeed right to consider writing your own library. However, does you test depend upon this outgoing request from SUT to robot framework? In my view a MockService that creates a file from the incoming request would allow the standard [Wait Untill Created](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Wait%20Until%20Created) keyword to work.

Comment: Thanks A. Koostra,   I was considering a MockService and might go that route.